# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist

I am getting the data from firestore and storing the data as List, Since the data from the firestore is map i couldn't save it correctly and i am getting this error.

my code.

```
getData() async{

final dataDB = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TransactionData').doc(getUid()).get();
    snapshot = dataDB;
    final Map documentData = snapshot.data() as Map;

    _cards = documentData as List?;

    setState(() {
      _data = _cards![0];
    });
  }
```

my data from Firestore.

```
{21Aug5298Sav: [{categoryName: Education, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 3,000.00, lastUpdatedDate: 25-08-2022, createdDate: 25-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: Credit, transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, auto: Y, accountName: null, transactionId: deb1621, categoryLogo: assets/images/Education.png, untagged: N, categoryBackgroundColor: 0xffFFA2C0, currency: INR, transactionDate: 25-08-2022}, {categoryName: Education, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 300.00, lastUpdatedDate: 25-08-2022, createdDate: 25-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: Debit, transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, auto: Y, accountName: null, transactionId: deb5366, categoryLogo: assets/images/Education.png, untagged: N, categoryBackgroundColor: 0xffFFA2C0, currency: INR, transactionDate: 25-08-2022}, {categoryName: Travelling, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 100.00, lastUpdatedDate: 24-08-2022, createdDate: 24-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: , transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, a<…>
```

i just want the list to contain all the data which was retrieved from the firestore. Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In the codes you had tried to cast a map as a list and assign it to the_cards variable. Try this

```
final Map documentData = snapshot.data() as Map;

_cards = documentData.values.toList();
//Or

_cards = documentData.values.toList().first;
```

**Edit**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _cards = [];
var allDocData = documentData.values.toList();

for(int i= 0; i < allDocData.length; i++)
 {
   _cards.add(allDocData[i] as Map<String, dynamic>);
}
```

Comment: For this also i will get the data as List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>. But i need List<Map<String, dynamic>> in this format.

Comment: Then .first is the one to use..`documentData.values.toList().first`

Comment: by using .first i can get only one List and second list data will be there.

Comment: now i am facing another issue, Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' 
 i am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/card_selector to show my data.

Comment: getting same error in this line _cards.add(allDocData[i]);

Comment: Try casting it.. Edited answer again

Answer (score 1):

You cant cast a Map to a List. Thats you error.
If you check your data, you will see that is not a List, it's a Map. If you want the list inside, you will need to access through the key "21Aug5298Sav"

Ex.

```
List _cards = documentData["21Aug5298Sav"]
```

Comment: i have already tried this method but the problem is that right now my documentData return 2 list and when i try to add that list in _cards i am getting list inside list List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>.

Comment: So, when you do documentData["21Aug5298Sav"], it returns two lists?

Comment: Yes, currently i have 3 lists in the documentData["21Aug5298Sav"].

Comment: Well, first you need to understand what the error means.
Second, you have to check what list you need. Do you need all the 3 lists? Or do you need just one? if so, the first one, the second one, or the third one.

Comment: i understood the error, i have updated the screenshot of firestore. please check this.

Comment: So you have a list of Map, you need to know what Map you need

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Map data = snapshot.data() as Map;
var firestoreResult = documentData.values.toList();
var finalResult = [];
for (var item in firestoreResult) {
  for (var x in item) {
     finalResult = [...finalResult, ...x];
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
setState(() {
   _data = finalResult![0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Data structure of my firestore data and its working perfectly. Thanks guys for your valuable time.